# Change color of the node in Pyvis Network when it gets clicked on

Tags: python, java, html, pyvis

I'm creating a network visualization in python using Pyvis. I can create the graph as I want with no problem, but when I run my script and get the html file as output, I want the nodes to change colors when I click on them and I can't achieve that. I've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work. The data I'm using has the following structure but with a lot more nodes than this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyvis.network import Network

data = [['A','B', 1], ['A','C', 4], ['B','A', 1], 
        ['D','E', 5], ['D','F', 1], ['G','J', 7],
        ['A','J', 4], ['G','F', 14], ['C','L', 4], 
        ['A','F', 2], ['E','H', 12], ['I','E', 2],
        ['I','K', 4], ['L','H', 21]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['source', 'target', 'feature_count']

# Step 1: Initialize Network
graph = Network(height='750px', width='100%', directed=True)

# Step 2: Get sources, targets and weights
sources = df['source']
targets = df['targets']
weights = df['feature_count']

edge_data = zip(sources, targets, weights)

# Step 3: Create the graph adding each node individually.
for edge in edge_data:  
    source_name = edge[0]
    target_name = edge[1]
    weight = edge[2]

    graph.add_node(n_id=source_name, label=source_name, labelHighlightBold=True)
    graph.add_node(n_id=target_name, label=target_name, labelHighlightBold=True)
    graph.add_edge(source_name, target_name, value=weight, title=weight, arrowStrikethrough=False)

# Step 4: Use the Json Dictionary that sets the options to specify that I want the color of the node to change to red when clicked on
options = {
    "configure": {
         "enabled": True
     },
    "interaction": {
        "hover": True
    },
    "nodes": {
         "borderWidth": 2,
         "borderWidthSelected": 4,
         "chosen" : True,
         "color": { "highlight": { "border": "#FF4040",
                                   "background": "#EE3B3B"
                     },
                    "hover": { "border": "#DEB887",
                               "background": "#FFD39B"
                     }
         }
     }
}

# Step 5: Define the options
graph.options = options


# Step 6: Visualize the Network
graph.show('graph.html')
```

For some reason this doesn't work. I've been searching for other possible solutions and I can't find them. It seems that the only thing left would be to create a function In Java that makes this and pass it to the html code. The thing is I don't know Java and I'm afraid to spend a lot of time trying that without getting to a solution or having another solution more quickly.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!